# Comparing cell contents against string in Excel

Tags: string, excel, if-statement, comparison

Following is my table

```
file:*.css  file:*.csS
file:*.PDF  file:*.PDF
file:*.ppt  file:*.xls
file:*.xls  file:*.doc
file:*.doc  file:*.CFM
file:*.dot  file:*.cfc
file:*.CFM  file:*.CFC
file:*.cfc  file:*.DOC
```

I need a formula to populate the H column with True or False if it finds column G in column F (exact case).

I used following but nothing seems to be resulting correct value, either it fails with case or if the same row didn't match returns false.

```
1 =IF(F2=(G$2:G$43), "True", "false") -> returns false if the same row didn't match.

2. =EXACT(F2,G$2:G$43) -> same as above

3. =MATCH(F2,G$2:G$41,0) -> fails with case sensitive.

4. =MATCH (TRUE, EXACT ( G$2:G$41, F2 ), 0 ) -> fails like #1
```

Comment: Do you want the match to be case sensitive ??

Comment: Yes... I wanted it to be case sensitive.... for example file:*.css  and file:*.csS should not match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need an **Array** formula.  In **G2** enter:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(1,--EXACT(F$2:F$7,E2),0)))
```

and copy down.

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

[image]

Note:  The curly brackets that appear in the Formula Bar should not be typed.